# Set an image as background in ion-slide

Tags: ionic2, background-image, slide

I am trying to do an intro for an app with **< ion-slides page>**, my problem comes to set an image as background, I am trying to do this on my HTML:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Intro</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>

<ion-slides pager>

  <ion-slide style="background-image: url(/../../www/img/fondo.png)">
    <h2>Slide 1</h2>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide style="background-color: mediumpurple">
    <h2>Slide 2</h2>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide style="background-color: mediumpurple">
    <h2>Slide 3</h2>
  </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

As it can be seen, the first slide should show the image, but what I get is this:
[image]

Thanks for helping!

Comment: you mean you get the background-color and not the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your background image path is incorrect.

The image should be saved in `/src/assets/img/fondo.png`.
This is copied to `/www/assets/img/fondo.png` during the build process.

Your html code will have :

```
 <ion-slide style="background-image: url(../assets/img/fondo.png)">
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Ionic 2+ I think this syntax is what you're looking for:

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let imgFile of imgList" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(../assets/image/' + imgFile)">
```